# how to skip the next line if condition c++

Tags: c++, getline

I had a look in other examples but I can't make this one work. 
I have a file that at some point has weird characters for example : "Äèîpg"
I don't want to save this line because it seems that the loop with getline will stop there (it stores until the line with the trash). How could I do it please? I know that when this occurs : "key =0", the next line will have these chars "Äèîpg".

Here is my code:

```
    file = "example.log";
    ifstream f(file);
    f.open(file);
    if (f.good()){
        while (getline(f, line)) {
            lineNumber++;
            if ((lineNumber>= line1 - 20) && (lineNumber<= line2)){
                pos = line.find("key = 0");
                if (pos != string::npos){
                    std::cout << "skip the line" << endl;

                }
                else{
                    Type v;
                    v.line= line;
                    v.index = lineNumber;
                    linesVector.push_back(v);
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    f.close();
```

Then I create a cut file with the info I need:

```
    ofstream myfile;    
    string merge =  file + "_Cut.log";  
    myfile.open(merge);     
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < linesVector.size(); i++){      
        myfile << linesVector[i].line << "\n";      
        //std::cout << linesVector[i].line << endl;     
    }   
    myfile.close();
```

Thank you in advance for your help !

To make clear how my file looks like, here it the original "example.log"
(I can't attach it somewhere).

```
2017-08-03 09:38:46 Expeum im6
2017-08-03 09:38:46 nubla4
2017-08-03 09:38:46 blaze
2017-08-03 09:38:46 ue
2017-08-03 09:38:46 er
2017-08-03 09:38:46 key = 0
2017-08-03 09:38:46 Q2žl2pE&ö³„Ôï¬ÈL+g…^cÎ1áø/7E›¸¥ü‰úLÎ’Æ
2017-08-03 09:38:46 81B9CEandrew499OEE4MUI5Q0VhbmRyZXc0OTk=
2017-08-03 09:38:47 B9CEandrew499OEE4MUI5Q0VhbmRyZXc0OTk=
2017-08-03 09:38:48 bla
2017-08-03 09:38:49 OK
2017-08-03 09:50:12  key = 0
2017-08-03 09:50:12 E&ö³„Ôï¬ÈL+g…^cÎ1áø/7E›¸¥ü‰úLÎ’Æ
```

and here is what I get in the cut file :

```
2017-08-03 09:38:46 Expeum im6
2017-08-03 09:38:46 nubla4
2017-08-03 09:38:46 blaze
2017-08-03 09:38:46 ue
2017-08-03 09:38:46 er
2017-08-03 09:38:46 key = 0
2017-08-03 09:38:46 Q2žl2p
```

The problem is that it is stuck in the last giberrish and cannot move on ! 
 Could it be some carriage return that is missing? I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: Worth investing some time with the debugger figuring out exactly what went goofy with "Äèîpg".  it could be a multi-character encoding and any of those characters could be containing an end of file marker or something that for one reason or another places the stream in an error state.

Comment: Hello, it is defacto that this happens in my txt file. My effort is to skip any line that is lead by the "key = 0" in the previous line.

Comment: `if (lineNumber >= line1 - 20 && lineNumber <= 2)` is much easier to read. The extra parentheses are distracting. It takes time to figure out that they don't mean anything.

Comment: ok, will fix it thank you

Comment: if there is more of that symbols you will have that problem again. if file format is determined consider check for valid code like `isalnum` + `isblank` + ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like you're trying to throw away the line "key = 0" and the next line?

If so you can just use [`ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) in the nested `if`-statement like this: `f.ignore(numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')`

If `lineNumber` should consider this a line you will also need to add `++lineNumber`.

If this could be the last line in the file you should add this code in total:

```
if(!f.ignore(numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')) {
    break;
}
++lineNumber;
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/6YEnu4)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am afraid I miss something here. Do you mean something like this?

if (pos != string::npos){
     std::cout << "skip the line" << endl;
     if (getline(f, line)) {
      ++lineNumber;
     }
     else {
      break;
     }
  
    }

It doesn't work for me. I think that the while (getline(f, line)) { creates an issue. Could you please post the code you mean in total ? I print 0 elements now.

Comment: thank you, but still doesn't work. It crushes after it finds the second time these chars

Comment: That is likely some other bug in your code. Your debugger should help with that.

Comment: @user6812514 I've typed up an example and added it to the answer, I suspect that your `line1` or `line2` is not what you intended.

Comment: thank you, I will try it with my file and I will get back to you

Comment: @user6812514 Here's what I'd suggest, since this answers the question of how you can skip a line that you should accept and then close this question. Then attempt to create a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating the bad behavior that you see now. Many times the creation of an MCVE will guide you to a solution. In the event that's not the case you should use the MCVE to create a new question.

Comment: @JonathanMee thank you for the example you attached. Your example works for your series of chars that you made but unfortunately not for my file. I order to make this clear, I edited my question, could you please have a look? Also my code that I attached originally was working in general but not for the giberish I had in my file. That is I am afraid the initial problem but is hard to realize and explain in the first place. How can I troubleshoot that? I m getting crazy with this.

Comment: @JonathanMee ok I will close the question, but in the new question I will make should I repost the same code to make it comprehensible? Then it will  be a double post. I put this title in the beginning because I thought I had a bug in my code :(