# Garbled characters that crush the access with getline, how to replace them?

Tags: c++, ifstream, getline, carriage-return

I tried to access a file that at some point has a lot of garbled characters. I know that this happens after a specific line (when this string if found with getline : "key = 0"). My goal is to get rid of it, replace the whole line with a string, ie. "hello", or force to have the **\n** char at the end. How can I do it? Have you faced it before? Here I explain my [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45576537/how-to-skip-the-next-line-if-condition-c/45576655?noredirect=1#comment78151180_45576655), but it doesn't manage so far to overcome the issue. It seems that there is no \n at the end of the line, or there is a char that cannot be read. Basically, I want to do programmatically what I would do with text "Replace all" command.

To make clear how my file looks like, here it the original "example.log" (I can't attach it somewhere).

```
2017-08-03 09:38:46 Expeum im6
2017-08-03 09:38:46 nubla4
2017-08-03 09:38:46 blaze
2017-08-03 09:38:46 ue
2017-08-03 09:38:46 er
2017-08-03 09:38:46 key = 0
2017-08-03 09:38:46 Q2žl2pE&ö³„Ôï¬ÈL+g…^cÎ1áø/7E›¸¥ü‰úLÎ’Æ
2017-08-03 09:38:46 81B9CEandrew499OEE4MUI5Q0VhbmRyZXc0OTk=
2017-08-03 09:38:47 B9CEandrew499OEE4MUI5Q0VhbmRyZXc0OTk=
2017-08-03 09:38:48 bla
2017-08-03 09:38:49 OK
2017-08-03 09:50:12  key = 0
2017-08-03 09:50:12 E&ö³„Ôï¬ÈL+g…^cÎ1áø/7E›¸¥ü‰úLÎ’Æ
```

and here is what I get in the cut file :

```
2017-08-03 09:38:46 Expeum im6
2017-08-03 09:38:46 nubla4
2017-08-03 09:38:46 blaze
2017-08-03 09:38:46 ue
2017-08-03 09:38:46 er
```

Comment: So with your desired output includes the "key = 0" lines, and everything else, *but* the lines immediately after the "key = 0" lines? Are you using Visual Studio? I'm just wondering if there could be something interpreted as an EOF character in those lines following?

Comment: Oops, I added the C++ tag. I forgot that would attract all the driveby downvoters. I'm sorry.

Comment: yes I m using visual studio indeed. why would they downvote it ? as I am writing in c++ i would like to have the tag.

Comment: My comment just expresses how jaded I am with C++ on http://www.stackoverflow.com For example the question that I just gave this answer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45617306/2642059 I don't know why there are so many driveby downvoters on the C++ tag. I'd totally be gone if there wasn't so much good information and Knowles here. I've written an appeal here that hopefully you find encouraging: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266670/2642059 Also have a +1 to offset.

Answer (score 0):

So this is easy to do... however if you have an EOF character in your string I don't know that it would have survived the transition to http://www.stackoverflow.com and then into my code. But I'm hoping that you simply have inverted your `break` logic from my 1<sup>st</sup> answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45576655/2642059

If this is the case then simple code like this should work fine:

```
tm iTm;
string iString;
const auto replaceAll = "hello";

while(f >> get_time(&iTm, " %Y - %m - %d %T ") && getline(f, iString)) {
    cout << put_time(&iTm, "%F %T ") << iString << endl;

    if(iString == "key = 0"s) {
        cout << put_time(&iTm, "%F %T ") << replaceAll << endl;
        if(!f.ignore(numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

From your input file this code gives me:

> 2017-08-03 09:38:46 Expeum im6
>   2017-08-03 09:38:46 nubla4
>   2017-08-03 09:38:46 blaze
>   2017-08-03 09:38:46 ue
>   2017-08-03 09:38:46 er
>   2017-08-03 09:38:46 key = 0
>   2017-08-03 09:38:46 81B9CEandrew499OEE4MUI5Q0VhbmRyZXc0OTk=
>   2017-08-03 09:38:47 B9CEandrew499OEE4MUI5Q0VhbmRyZXc0OTk=
>   2017-08-03 09:38:48 bla
>   2017-08-03 09:38:49 OK
>   2017-08-03 09:50:12 key = 0

I've written an example: http://rextester.com/JCKF84982 but you'll need to swap the `istringstream` for an `ifstream`.